# Slow down a specific set of extruder moves

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I'm printing a keychain. In fact, I'll soon be printing a LOT of these keychains (they'll be available to everyone at a school).

After a couple test prints everything looks good... except for one little issue. During the first layer, there's a problem with the first wall extrusion for the eye hole the metal keyring will eventually pass through. Being so small, it doesn't like to adhere to the bed.

I could probably resolve this by tightening up the bed level. However, I already like the level position for the rest of the print, and from experience I know going much tighter will start to make it difficult to remove items or even leave grooves in the print mat. I could also resolve this by slowing the down the first layer... and if it were just one key chain that's what I'd do. But for a few hundred of these I'd like to see if I can optimize this some more. As it is, it adds 20 seconds or so to a print that's otherwise only 10 minutes long. It's enough to add up.

I've also been through the G-Code in a text editor, but so far I haven't been able to identify the moves in question.

Is there a way I can slow down just one set of extrusion moves?

Answer (score 1):

You can use G-code [`M220`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M220.html) (Set Feedrate Percentage).

You need to first identify the part that needs to be printed slowly, an online G-code interpreter can help you visualize this. Once located, insert the G-code to store the current value with `M220 B`, change to a lower speed `M220 S20`, print the key ring part and restore the speed to the stored value `M220 R`.